# Gitlab SSH Deploy to a Server Permissions error

Tags: git, ssh, server, gitlab

**Scope:**
I have cloned my Gitlab project to the local machine and committed new changes. After that, I push changes to Gitlab, that has a runner, which deploys changes to the remote server via SSH sshpass. Changes do get deployed, however, Git throws the following Permissions denied error (I have marked out the sensitive data):

```
scp: /*******/*******/public_html/*******/./.git/objects/6e/b8f993a41829a041ce6edb0f62ce9eb08fa4e5: Permission denied
scp: /*******/*******/public_html/*******/./.git/objects/cc/755f430fd5ffed100da5e46026ede6316b8723: Permission denied
scp: /*******/*******/public_html/*******/./.git/objects/fb/d81f2bc416e83ab746e7fa97c1fa20affe3116: Permission denied
scp: /*******/*******/public_html/*******/./.git/objects/cb/7e87f324ab04fe319606e0c429a96de383dc2f: Permission denied
```

What would be the solution here? How to chown privileges, so that the pipeline would succeed?

Comment: Does the user (git/gitlab uses) on the servers have read/write permissions on those files? You could try running `chmod u+rw /*******/*******/public_html/*******/./.git` if the user is the owner of these files..

Comment: @dan1st is this on my local machine or the remote server?

Comment: @dan1st .git directory permissions are ```drwxrwxrwx```